# Mysql - Sql Query sum and filter

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, prestashop-1.6

I want to show my query just only who total order bigger then 200

For now my query is

```
SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid
FROM
    ps_orders
    RIGHT JOIN ps_customer 
        on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE
    ps_orders.total_paid > 1
ORDER BY
    ps_orders.id_customer;
```

Showing like this

```
 id_customer    firstname   lastname    email   total_paid
--------------------------------------------------------
55  name8   name10  ***@windowslive.com 88.90
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    56.00
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    87.90
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    79.99
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
59  name3   name5   ****@hotmail.com    123.83
60  name    name2   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
```

I want show like this

```
 id_customer    firstname   lastname    email   total_paid
--------------------------------------------------------
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    302.49
```

Comment: `ps_orders.total_paid > 200`?

Comment: @Lashane that is showing only which order was bigger then 200 not making sum

Comment: It's worth noting that a search for "RIGHT JOIN" on SO presently returns 1530 results, as compared with a search for "LEFT JOIN", which presently returns 17960 results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Group by ps_orders.id_customer having sum(ps_orders.total_paid) > 200
```

«Group by» group your data and having make sum of the group

Edit: «where» can't do aggregate functions.

```
SELECT  ps_orders.id_customer,
ps_customer.firstname,
ps_customer.lastname,
ps_customer.email,
sum(ps_orders.total_paid) as totalOrder
```

....... 
    Group by ps_orders.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email  having sum(ps_orders.total_paid) > 200

Comment: that is making just sum that group that is okay but i don't want show which is less then 200 if i make like this showing to me id_customer 60 total paid 78.90.

Comment: Have you put the having clause?

Comment: I just try like this SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid
FROM
    ps_orders
    RIGHT JOIN ps_customer 
        on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
Group by ps_orders.id_customer 
having sum(ps_orders.total_paid) > 200

Comment: Put in group by all the expressions of select clause

Comment: Group by ps_orders.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email, ps_orders.total_paid

Comment: you mean changing that Group line with   Group by ps_orders.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email, ps_orders.total_paid and looks like this "Group by ps_orders.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email, ps_orders.total_paid having sum(ps_orders.total_paid) > 200 " ?

Comment: If it's like this not working. "Group by ps_orders.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email, ps_orders.total_paid having sum(ps_orders.total_paid) > 200" Cuz showing same result.

Comment: SELECT  ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    sum(ps_orders.total_paid) as totalOrder    ....... Group by ps_orders.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email  having sum(ps_orders.total_paid) > 200

Comment: Yes now is working well thank you so much if you want edit your answers with this :)